# Flutter TextOverflow not working in Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, overflow

I have Column which consists of 2 Text widget in it and I tried to apply TextOverflow.ellipsis to the widgets when the string is too long. However, the overflow doesnt seems working as I stil get the "RenderFlex Overflow" error. Can anyone tell me how to solve this? The below is my sample code:

```
Row(children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Text(data.picodedesc,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              softWrap: false,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                          Text(data.description,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              maxLines: 1,
                              softWrap: false,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
Row(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text(data.picodedesc,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        softWrap: false,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                    Text(data.description,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: false,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ]
)
```

Comment: I tried this way before but the overflow is still not working...

Comment: @Leong is the `Row` a child widget of another `Row` or `Column`?

Comment: Yes. this is a child of another Row

Comment: @Leong is your problem solved? if not, you can provide the full code of your widget, i will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap with `Expanded()` with your `Row()` widget, Otherwise You can  set the fix width for your `Row()` widget with `Container()` or `SizedBox()`.

It's look like below code :

```
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        data.picodedesc,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        softWrap: false,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        data.description,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: false,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Hope this solution might be work for you.